# PostgreSQL search in table with type timestamp without timezone

Tags: php, jquery, sql, postgresql, search

I need to search all columns in a Postgres table using a string.But it causes error for column with type "timestamp without timezone";
It shows the error:"ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to search a `timestamp` using the `LIKE` operator (internally `~~`). That cannot work, because that operator does not exist for datetime data types.

You will have to cast the `timestamp` to a string data type:

```
WHERE CAST(timestamp_col AS text) LIKE '2021-%'
```

or, better, explicitly format it as string:

```
WHERE to_char(timestamp_col, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') LIKE '2021-%'
```